# Product based gallery, dynamic title not working properly

Tags: php, wordpress

This is the link of the site: https://www.silvanacasciaro.it/ 
The gallery is the one with the shoes and bags after the 3 round images of the collections, next to "i nostri brand". The problem is that whatever image you click on, the little title on the top left shows the name of the first image no matter what and starts from there, instead of showing the actual name of the photo a clicked on. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the html:

```
    <div id="blueimp-gallery" class="blueimp-gallery">
        <!-- The container for the modal slides -->
        <div class="slides"></div>
        <!-- Controls for the borderless lightbox -->
        <h3 class="title"></h3>
        <!-- <p class="description"></p> -->
        <a class="prev">‹</a>
        <a class="next">›</a>
        <a class="close">×</a>
        <a class="play-pause"></a>
        <ol class="indicator"></ol>
        <!-- The modal dialog, which will be used to wrap the lightbox content -->
        <div class="modal fade">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body next"></div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left prev">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i>
                            Previous
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary next">
                            Next
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here is the js:

```
    <script src="//blueimp.github.io/Gallery/js/jquery.blueimp-gallery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/js/bootstrap-image-gallery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    document.getElementById('links').onclick = function (event) {
          event = event || window.event;
          var target = event.target || event.srcElement,
            link = target.src ? target.parentNode : target,
            options = {
              index: link, event: event,
              onclose: function () {
                        // Callback function executed when the Gallery is about to be closed.
                        jQuery('body').css('overflow','auto !important');
                    },
              onslide: function (index, slide) {
                self = this;
                var initializeAdditional = function (index, data, klass, self) {
                  var text = self.list[index].getAttribute(data),
                    node = self.container.find(klass);
                  node.empty();
                  if (text) {
                    node[0].appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
                  }
                };

                initializeAdditional(index, 'data-title', '.title', self);
              }
            },
            links = this.getElementsByTagName('a');
          blueimp.Gallery(links, options);

    };
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is getting parent a element.
In this line you are trying to get parent a element:

```
link = target.src ? target.parentNode : target,
```

But actually it gets

```
<div class="image_wrapper">
<img class="" alt="Tronchetto | Silvana Casciaro" src="https://www.silvanacasciaro.it/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/CHIARINI-BOLOGNA-tronchetto.jpg">
</div>
```

The only thing you need to do to solve this issue is replacing target.parentNode with target.parentNode.parentNode and to get this:

```
link = target.src ? target.parentNode.parentNode : target,
```

In that case variable "link" will get correct object and the code will start working:

```
<a href="https://www.silvanacasciaro.it/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/LIU-JO-–-Zaino-Romantica2.jpg" data-title="Zaino Romantica" data-gallery="#blueimp-gallery" class="maggiori_info" title="Zaino Romantica">
      <div class="image_wrapper">
              <img class="" alt="Zaino Romantica | Silvana Casciaro" src="https://www.silvanacasciaro.it/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/LIU-JO-–-Zaino-Romantica2.jpg">
            </div><!--image_wrapper-->
       <h4 class="prod_title">Zaino Romantica</h4>
       <button class="btn btn-lg">Scopri</button>
     </a>
```

p.s. Your code also has some another issues and you may need to debug it in your browser console.

Comment: It works, thank you very much! Anyway yes il keep looking into the code, again thank you for the help.